# Animation in Imageview

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-animation

I have two images. If I click on the first image, the image will fade down and the second image will be visible (Initially the second image will have alpha=0). Now, when I click the second image it should fade down and the first image should be visible .

How can I make it work?  The main code is given below :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public void fade(View image){
    ImageView tom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tom.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

}


public void fade1(View image1){
    ImageView jerry = (ImageView) image1;
    jerry.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: just use `android.widget.ImageSwitcher`

Comment: how to use it in my code?

Comment: did you see the `ImageSwitcher` documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @AravindD "how to use it my code" feels like you are expecting someone to giv you the code so you can simply copy-paste it. However, am not against it, but its always a good practice to understand the code before actually using it. I know most of us probably want to "get the job done", but you might want to consider other parameters (for instance, performance impact and so on), before implementing it. Cheers!